# При отправке запроса с JSP в MySQL, в БД отображает "кракозябры" вместо русского текста

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, utf-8, unicode

Добрый вечер! Возникла проблема при внесении данных в БД MySQL с JSP страницы.
Когда вношу русский текст в БД, то отображает "кракозябры".[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже поменял на UTF-8 всё что можно. Вот моя JSP страница

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<%@ page session="false"%>
<%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType ("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link
    href="<c:url value="/resources/registration/css/registration.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/login/inputs/demo.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/registration/inputs/set2.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/registration/css/fontsReg.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/registration/css/buttonsReg.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/login/inputs/normalize.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body class="bgrReg">
<div id="header">
    <img src="<c:url value="/resources/logo/logo.png"/>"/>
</div>
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
    <h5>(все поля обязательны к заполнению)</h5>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left_block">
            <a href="login"><button class="slide_from_left">Назад</button></a>

        </div>
        <div id="right_block">
            <c:url var="saveUrl" value="registration" />
            <form:form modelAttribute="users" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}"
                class="formular">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="username" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-32" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-32">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Логин</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="password" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="password" id="input-33" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-33">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Пароль</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="name" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Имя</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="surname" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Фамилия</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="email" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Email</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:select
                                    class="selectStyle" path="gender">
                                <form:option value="Мужской"></form:option> 
                                    <form:option value="Женский"></form:option>
                                </form:select></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="age" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Возраст</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="weight" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Вес</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="height" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Рост</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="sport" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Спортивные
                                        навыки</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"><form:select
                                    path="place">
                                    <form:option value="Дзержинский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Киевский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Комминтерновский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Лененский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Московский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Октябрский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Орджоникидзевский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Фрунзенский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Холодная гора"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Червонозаводской"></form:option>
                                </form:select></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami">
                                <button class="slide_from_left" type="submit">Регистрация</button>
                                <!-- <input type="submit"
                        value="<spring:message text="Регистрация"/>" /> -->
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <form:input path="enabled" type="hidden" value="true" />
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Но когда вношу в MySQL вручную русские символы в таблицу - отображает корректно. Уже не пойму в чём проблема.

Comment: В какой IDE работаете? Какой сервер используете?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего создать фильтр, чтобы при каждом запросе кодировка `UTF-8` была.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                     ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws ServletException {
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```